# Maximum message limit while sending message through incoming webhook

Tags: google-hangouts

I am sending notification to chat rooms through incoming web hooks. I am using powershell and using following command:
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $hangoutURL -Method Post -Body $payload -ContentType 'html'

My question is what is the maximum size limit of text message that could be sent through this command?

Answer (score 2):

Testing this endpoint using `curl`, I have obtained the following response message:

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Message is longer than 4096 characters",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

This restriction applies to the content of your request. That is, if you have a request body like the following:

```js
{
  "text": "hello world"
}
```

This restriction applies to the contents of the value associated to the `text` key.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to increase this limit?

Comment: @ShishirKavle Sadly - there is no way of increasing it. In order to overcome this limitation you could split your response into more than one messages (of less than 4096 characters each).

Comment: Thanks again. This helps!

Comment: @ShishirKavle No worries! Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in case my answer was useful to you. Have a good day!

Comment: It seems the limit as of today is now 32,000 characters.